# How to use heirarchical tags with Ecto

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, ecto

I would like a tag with parent and children tags, such that `tag.parents` and `tag.children` would each return a different list of tags.

Is this possible to do without writing my own queries?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it. I created a tag_relationship table first:

```
create table(:tag_relationship, primary_key: false) do
  add :parent_id, references(:tags)
  add :child_id, references(:tags)
end
```

Give it a schema & changeset

```
defmodule Notebook.TagRelationship do
  use Notebook.Web, :model

  @primary_key false
  schema "tag_relationship" do
    belongs_to :parent, Tag
    belongs_to :child, Tag
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
     |> cast(params, [:parent_id, :child_id])
     |> validate_required([:parent_id, :child_id])
  end
end
```

Now setup the many_to_many relationships all within the tag model

```
schema "tags" do
  field :name, :string
  many_to_many :parents, Notebook.Tag, [join_through: Notebook.TagRelationship, 
    join_keys: [child_id: :id, parent_id: :id]]
  many_to_many :children, Notebook.Tag, [join_through: Notebook.TagRelationship, 
    join_keys: [parent_id: :id, child_id: :id]]
  timestamps()
end
```

I explicitly set the key names since I didn't know what it might try to infer.

Now I can create relationships with the TagRelationship changeset

```
c = TagRelationships.changeset(%TagRelationship{},
      {parent_id: a.id, child_id: b.id})
Repo.insert(c)
```

for tags a, b